# Tracking over 500 events per session

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I'm about to launch a web-site very soon, and I want to track over 500 actions per session.  Basicall, I want to track each hover-over, and Google Analytics only supports 500 actions per session.  What is the best way to do this reliably but also a relatively inexpensive solution.  I'm thinking of something like this...

1. Batch up events on the client
2. Send via ajax every N events or seconds
3. Write to a pretty cheap but reliable persistent store

Comment: Maybe Google Analytics won't be the best tool for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

1. To batch up the events, simple push them into your own javascript object, maybe with the same signature:

   yourEventArray.push(['Category','Action', 'Label']);
2. Create a function that gets called on some interval:

   ...page load event...
   var gaqTimeout = setTimeout(uploadEvent, 100);

   function uploadEvent() {
      if (yourEventArray.length > 0) {
          // do something like loop through items in array and pop them out once added to _gaq
      }
   }
3. How does this apply?  If you're talking about queuing GA events to the server for later processing, you should really think about finding a better solution that handles your specific situation.

**UPDATE** - based on your comment

Other products that I familiar with that do a good job tracking hover events and mouse events:

- [ClickPath](http://www.clickpath.com/)
- You could use [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) with [Custom Variables](http://piwik.org/docs/custom-variables/) as Events
- [Yahoo! web analytics](http://web.analytics.yahoo.com/)

Lastly, [check out this great post](http://www.webanablog.com/2010/01/07/omniture-google-yahoo-analytics-comparison/) that contrasts 3 of the most popular Web Analytics tools and their limitations.

My 2 cents, hope it gets you in the right direction!

Comment: Ooops... I meant is there a solution other than using Google Analytics?

Comment: Updated to reflect your comment.  I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

[Mixpanel](http://www.mixpanel.com) is based on events and there are no limits. It is not free, but it is awesome for this use case.

Comment: I think it is severely overpriced.

Comment: If you are currently spending little to nothing on an analytics solution, I can see your point, but as compared with other competing tools in the marketplace, or developing a custom solution, it's competitively priced. If you have a free or open source product or are a not-for-profit company, consider contacting them and plead your case for a discount license.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to study the [Measurement Protocol in Google's Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). You could define all your actions as virtual pageviews, and have up to 10M a month.

See also the [Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/limits-quotas).

The limit you describe, of 500 events per session, may not actually be that big of a deal if you re-think it a bit. Realize that a Google Analytics session is (most likely) not the same thing as *your user logging into your app and doing things*.

You might want to try setting a custom dimension of "LoggedIn" to "Yes" when someone logs in, but "No" otherwise. Send this CD with every pageview and event. This is a more typical idea of a session in a web app. Then every pageview or event you send to GA can be analyzed within the context of this dimension.

Additional References

- http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/08/update-to-sessions-in-google-analytics.html
- http://www.analytics-ninja.com/blog/2011/08/how-google-analytics-calculates-visits.html
- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets
- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en